# Shapes not aligned in numpy ValueError when both matrices have same dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I wrote this function:

```
def update_parameters(t0, t1, lrate, x_matrix, x_vector, y_vector):
    # Create a 2x1 dimensional vector with t0 and t1
    hypothesis_vector = np.r_['c', [t0, t1]]
    prediction_vector = np.dot(x_matrix, hypothesis_vector)
    
    error_vector = np.subtract(prediction_vector, y_vector)
    
    # Debugging, remove later
    print(f'Dimensions: {np.ndim(error_vector)}, {np.ndim(x_vector)}')
    print(f'Shape: {error_vector.shape}, {x_vector.shape}')
    print(f'Length: {len(error_vector)}, {len(x_vector)}')
    
    derivative_vector = error_vector * x_vector
    
    # Calculate partial derivative of cost function.
    t0_derivative = np.sum(error_vector)
    t0 = t0 - (t0_derivative * lrate)
    
    t1_derivative = np.sum(derivative_vector)
    t1 = t1 - (t1_derivative * lrate)
    
    return t0, t1
```

And when I ran it, I got this traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-10848703fdbf> in <module>
----> 1 test = update_parameters(0, 1, 0.5, trainset_x_matrix, trainset_x_vector, trainset_y_vector)
      2 print(test)

<ipython-input-113-6c8da5390608> in update_parameters(t0, t1, lrate, x_matrix, x_vector, y_vector)
     26     print(f'Length: {len(error_vector)}, {len(x_vector)}')
     27 
---> 28     derivative_vector = error_vector * x_vector
     29 
     30     # Calculate partial derivative of cost function.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __mul__(self, other)
    218         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    219             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 220             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    221         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    222             return N.dot(self, other)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (101,1) and (101,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 101 (dim 0)
```

I wrote some print statements to get the dimensions of both `x_vector` and `error_vector` and got this output:

```
Dimensions: 2, 2
Shape: (101, 1), (101, 1)
Length: 101, 101
```

and they appear to be same. Why is it saying that they are not aligned? When I searched for this error, it was for people who were operating on matrices with different dimensions. I am confused and any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: `np.dot` is matrix multiplication.  Do you remember in high school or college running your finger across the rows of one matrix and down the columns of the other?  Read the documentation for `np.dot`!

Comment: I am not trying to do a dot, it was supposed to be an element by element multiplication. Is what I did wrong?

Comment: Oops I missed that fact that the `dot` is in a `np.matrix` calculation.  For `np.matrix` subclass arrays, `*` is the `dot`.  Why do you have np.matrix` arrays?   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html